# Parsing Json array inside jsonobject in android

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-volley

```
[
  {
    "subject": "Top exotic beaches in Greece",
    "participants": [
      "Aristotle", "Socrates"
    ],
    "preview": "Plato,\nThis is what I was talking about for the bachelor party!",
    "isRead": false,
    "isStarred": true,
    "ts": 1471451322,
    "id": 5
  }
]
```

How to parse "participants" from this json... thanx in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to parse JSON in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android)

Comment: i have updated my question now can anyone tell me how to parse and save in arraylist

Comment: Updated answer to show how you can parse through the JSON array and save it to an array list

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    JSONArray participants = jsonObject.getJSONArray("participants")
    for (int i = 0; i < participants.length(); i++) {
        yourArrayList.add(participants.getString(i))
    }
} catch(JSONException e) {
    // Handle exception.
}
```

Comment: if there is two values inside participants like [abc, xyz] then how to parse and save in arraylist

Comment: Value Socrates at 0 of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: Switch participants.getString(i) to participants.getJSONObject(i)

Comment: If the contents of your participants array are strings, you use getString(i), and getJSONObject(i) if they're objects. Your compiler is telling you that they're strings but you're trying to access them as JSON objects.

Comment: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference.. I am using List<String> to save the data inside participants and i am getting this error.

Comment: Make sure you initialize the array list before adding things to it: List<String> yourArrayList = new ArrayList<>;

Answer (score 1):

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(mainJSON.getJSONArray("participants"))
```

Then you just use your object like this:

```
 jsonArray.getJSONObject(0)
```

Comment: i am getting an error jsonexception: not a primitive array